# Computing font truetype hhea values (ascender, descender)

Tags: fonts, truetype, opentype

I'm trying to parse truetype font for building and store the ascender, descender for each fontsize, I'm using http://nodebox.github.io/opentype.js/ that did an amazing work, but I don't understand how to compute the returned values.

Example font Blackoak (adobe)
I've got [Ascender, Descender] = 1900 and -500

I presume that these numbers indicates the distance from the baseline in em space, but did I need other meta information for computing these values?

Comment: Here the formula to get the correct value in pixel = Ascender * scale(fontSize)/unitsPerEm (for mm conversion just multiply by 25.4 and divide by 72 dpi..

Answer (score 5):

If you want to compute ascender/descender in pixels for specific font size, then you need to lookup `OS/2` table for `sTypoAscender` and `sTypoDescender` values (as instructed by [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#leading)). The `ascender` and `descender` values of `hhea` table are marking only [font designer's intention](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/TrueType-Reference-Manual/RM06/Chap6hhea.html) which **not** necessarily corresponds to real computed values. Concerning value type, you're right, ascender and descender are in UPM units and negative means below the baseline.

In order to convert these numbers to pixels for specific font size you also need to extract how many *units per em* are in your font. You can do that by reading `unitsPerEm` value from the `head` table. Usually, for OTF its 1000 UPM, for TTF - 1024 or 2048 UPM. Absolute values of `sTypoAscender` and `sTypoDescender` should add up to `unitsPerEm` value. And then its just a matter of ratio.

For example, lets take a look at the opentype.js [Font Inspector](http://opentype.js.org/font-inspector.html) and assume 16px font size.  Value `unitsPerEm` is 2048 UPM, `sTypoAscender` and `sTypoDescender` are 1536 and -512 correspondingly (1536 + 512 = 2048):

```
 Ascender = 16 * 1536/2048 = 12px  (above baseline)
Descender = 16 * -512/2048 = -4px  (below baseline)
```