# Calculating baseline in Raphael.text with OpenType

Tags: fonts, raphael, opentype

Using `Raphael.text` and `getBBox` I obtain the full dimensions of the text from ascender to descender. Therefor the getBBox method does not accurately reflect the actual height of my text. The height for my test is 90px.

[image]

I've integrated OpenType and use that to draw the same text in an invisible canvas and pass that to `Raphael.pathBBox` which returns the exact dimensions of my text. The height of this is 70px.

[image]

Now my task is to be able to line up the texts. In order to do so I need to know the ascender/descender in pixels for the OpenType text.

I read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19856094/computing-font-truetype-hhea-values-ascender-descender) which says to not use the hhea table but instead the os2 values for the ascender/descender. However when I add up the final values my total is around 70px and not the desired 90px. If I instead use the hhea values I get 90px. Also note that in this post it claims that the ascender/descender will addup to the unitsperem but they do not in my case when I use the os2 table values. Perhaps the os2 table only reflects data from the fonts I used rather than the entire glyphs?

is the hhea really not fine to use? And since the os2 table do not yield the correct info then how to obtain it.

Here's a print of the hhea/os2 tables.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer in the OpenType issues: https://github.com/nodebox/opentype.js/issues/110

Opentype provide `font.ascender` and `font.descender` values. So:

```
var aboveBaseline = font.ascender / font.unitsPerEm * fontSize;
var belowBaseline = font.descender / font.unitsPerEm * fontSize;
var boundingBoxHeight = aboveBaseline + belowBaseline
```