# TrueType Font: Where is the baseline in the em square?

Tags: fonts, truetype

I am reading a TrueType Font file for rendering text. One information I cannot seem to find is **the baseline position inside the em square**.

Assuming that the em square will resemble the line height, how will I place the glyphs in a line when their coordinate origin is at 0 (baseline)?

[image]

From [Computing font truetype hhea values (ascender, descender)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19856094/computing-font-truetype-hhea-values-ascender-descender) I believed that values `sTypoAscender` and `sTypoDescender` might point me at the correct placement, but a) these values are contained in the *optional* table `OS/2` and b) for font `Arial` (with which I'm experimenting at the moment) those values are     1491 and -431, but 1491 + 431 = 1922 ≠ 2048 (em square).

Is the information I'm looking for contained in the TTF file? If not, what are best-practice solutions/approximations?

Answer (score 0):

See microsoft's opentype [documentation:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/os2#stypoascender)

> It is not a general requirement that sTypoAscender - sTypoDescender be
> equal to unitsPerEm. These values should be set to provide default
> line spacing appropriate for the primary languages the font is
> designed to support.

So there are recommendations for metric values, but font designers might deviate from these.

With regards to the Arial, you might use this calculation:

```js
/**
* retrieved from opentype.js font object:
* upm =  font.unitsPerEm
* ascender =  font.ascender
* descender =  font.descender
* sCapHeight =  font.tables.os2.sCapHeight
*/
let upm = 2048;
let ascender = 1854;
let descender = 434;
let lineGap = 67;
let sCapHeight = 1467;

// get scaling factor
let fontSize = 100;
let scale = fontSize/upm;
let capH = ( upm -(ascender-lineGap)  )*scale;
let baseL =  ((upm - ascender) + lineGap + sCapHeight  ) * scale

capHeight.style.top = capH+'px';
baseline.style.top = baseL+'px';
```

```css
body{
  font-family:Arial;
}

h1{
  position:relative;
  font-size: 100px;
  line-height:1em;
  outline: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow: visible;
}

.metrics{
  position: absolute;
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  border-top: 1px dotted red;
}

.green{
  border-color: green
}
```

```html
<h1 id="h1">Hamburgefons 
  <span class="metrics" id="capHeight"></span>
  <span class="metrics green" id="baseline"></span></h1>
```

Comment: In digital type, the em square functions as a pivot, or reference: it's used mainly to determine how the font's internal coordinate system relates to the text size. (Setting text size to 12 pt means that the em height is 12 pt.) As herrstrietzel indicates, the font designer isn't constrained to set metric values so they add up to one em. But also, the distance from the top of a frame to the baseline or from one baseline to the next baseline is something that an app or content author (via an app) can set at their discretion. The sTypo* values in the font are the designers recommended default.